# Issue in module Complie

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am creating a application with multiple modules. **Project Name : A,Module : B,Module : C**
I have to access features of Module : C in project : A and Module B .
Thus their build.gradle is as

**Module : B :-
implementation project(‘:C’)
And Project : A is 
implementation project(‘:C’)
implementation project(‘:B’)**

Is there any when anyway I can use implementation project(‘:C’) only in Module B build.gradle and use it in my Project: A

**Like: 
Module : B :-
implementation project(‘:C’)
And Project : A :- 
implementation project(‘:B’)**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `implementation` with `api`. `implementation` ensures that dependencies do not leak in parent module.

`api` is replacement for `compile`. This allows dependencies to be used in parent module. So you can do:

**In module B:**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api project(':C') 
}
```

**In module A:**

```
dependencies {
    ....
    api project(':B')
}
```

You can replace `api` in Module A with `implementation` if you wish to restrict usage of Module B in parent module of Module A